# Can't get GMP lib compiling with Emscripten (2)

Tags: c++, gmp, emscripten

I'm a bit a newb. My system is OSX.

I've gotten emscripten working with SDL2 which is awesome. I compile with the command:

```
./emcc /Users/elliotmacneille/Projects/the\ simplifier/the\ simplifier/main.cpp -s USE_SDL=2 -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -std=c++11 -o money99.html
```

from command line within the emscripten directory.

Now I wish to get GMP working with it. I have the header files, libgmp.a, and libgmp.10.dylib on my computer, but I dont know where to put them for emscripten.
I have also made a gmp.js using emscripten, again not sure where to put it.

Whenever I try to compile I get this:

```
"fatal error: 
      'gmp.h' file not found
#include <gmp.h>
         ^
1 error generated."
```

Where should I put the header files and what library should I put where?
I have no trouble compiling libgmp in Xcode, but I want to use emscripten.

Comment: I figured out the header file...I put them all of gmp's in ...emscripten/incoming/system/local/include. I still do not know where to put the library itself. the error I get now is: warning: unresolved symbol: 
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_init
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_abs
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_add
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_clear
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_set_str

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell the compiler where the library headers are using the `-I` command line option, and then which libraries to link to using the `-l` command line option. Something like:

```
emcc myfile.cpp -o myoutput.html -Lpath/to/gmp/include -lgmp
```

This isn't emscripten-specific: it's how C/C++ compilers like GCC and LLVM usually work. You didn't have to do this for SDL because [it's special](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-do-i-link-against-system-libraries-like-sdl-boost-etc)!

You won't be able to just used `libgmp.a` or `libgmp.10.dylib` though! Those target x86 (or at least they do on your Mac), and you want them to either be LLVM bitcode or JavaScript. There doesn't seem to be an easily-available gmp port, so the easiest is probably to [build it yourself and link it into your application](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#building-projects).

gmp usually builds with inline assembly but you can disable this from its build. It may be useful to check out [how this was done for PNaCl inside of naclports](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/naclports/+/master/ports/gmp/build.sh), and doing the same thing for your own build.

Comment: by      "-I"  do you mean     "-L"